# User Profile keeps loading TEMP Profile

Tags: profile

I am having a difficult time with an issue that our support staff won't support (as they will not support Vista).  I am able to log into our domain without any issue, however, when I go home and log into my domain account (disconnected), everything works great.  I log out that night, redock my computer on our domain network and BLAMO, I get loaded into a TEMP profile.

When I look under the event view, I get the following messages.  There are 3 others that follow it, relating to this event, however, I don't want to spam the threads unless you deem it necessary.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service
Date:          6/3/2009 6:53:21 AM
Event ID:      1508
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      xxx
Description:
Windows was unable to load the registry. This problem is often caused by insufficient memory or insufficient security rights. 

 DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
 for C:\Users\xxx\ntuser.dat
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" Guid="{89B1E9F0-5AFF-44A6-9B44-0A07A7CE5845}" />
    <EventID>1508</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2009-06-03T11:53:21.416184400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2156</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{02CFD900-F800-0000-E482-E0C041E4C901}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="112" ThreadID="304" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxx/Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData Name="EVENT_REGLOADKEYFAILED">
    <Data Name="Error">The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
</Data>
    <Data Name="File">C:\Users\xxx\ntuser.dat</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I'm just frustrated that I can't get support and most of the search articles I came across had to do with local accounts.  I did make a backup of the "functioning" profile, in hopes to restore that once everything is back to normal.

I've logged in as a local admin to the box and renamed the "corrupt" profile in hopes that it would simply be rebuilt when I logged back into my domain account.  However, when I did that, it STILL logged into the TEMP profile...grr!

Thanks in advanced, 
Aaron

Answer (score 6):

To generate a new profile along with renaming the user profile folder, you also need to remove the profile from the registry. This is found in HKLM/software/Microsoft/windows nt/current version/profilelist Scroll through until you find the correct username. Delete this string and then log back onto the computer with the account and it will create a new user profile and will no longer logon with a temp profile.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate all of the responses and I apologize if my question was out of context for the site.  The issue was finally resolved with some removals of the computer account from the domain, as well as deletion of the temp and domain user profiles on the local machine.  Again, I apologize if this is out of context for the site.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with an imaged hard drive. The user account would not create a profile and there wasn't any in the registry marked as bad.  The profile was an AD profile marked as roaming. My AD admin account had worked fine so I suspected it was a permissions issue. I took the path out of the users AD account settings then reapplied permissions on the hard drive for the C:\USERS folder and logged in as the user again.  That corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The following from the MS KB may be helpful:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960464/

It would seem to describe the same issues.

As an aside, why were you given a laptop with an OS your support staff don't support?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will apply to you but I've had problems like this before where I work.

Often times when users are getting loaded with the TEMP profile it's because the C: is almost out of space. I think it causes problems when it tries to write data to the user profile located on C:\Users\etc... I was often able to simply clear up some space on the C: and the profile would load.

Maybe this applies to you as it does seem like a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same exact thing but, here is what I experienced.

We enabled roaming profiles. User reports this same issue (temp/default profile loaded, desktop icons/background askew,etc...). We'd have to go into the server, delete the user folder data & then have the user connect on a wired link. The server would then load the profile from users machine & copy all data. No other corruption had occurred. It seemed this was prevelent when a user had used a bad wireless connection with high latency. It responded enough that it didn't disconnect him (even over vpn at a cafe) but, it was enough to cause corruption and invalid crc checks. We also noticed that when we switched the DC to a Gig switch the problem decreased.

Comment: oh yea, if you feel your old profile is wacked, you may want to try out profwiz to migrate the settings to another profile (if possible). I've had some success with this but, mileage may vary.

http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I had a server change but the roaming profiles were left on the older server that is now just a member server.  In AD under the the users profile tab it was using the  variable (%logonserver%\profiles\%username%) in the profile path. That server is no longer the logonserver - I changed it to (\servername\profiles\%username%)

This syntax could be running in a script too at login and you might need to change it there.